# Is there a quick way to strip out a specific character from all the rows in one column in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to strip out the date from a column and make it a new column. I wrote a function to do it, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the pandas framework.

Here's the original df:

```
ID                       var1   var2 
abc_20190503_xyz         100    10
fds_20190503_fnk         234    32
ree_20190503_fds         555    23
```

I wrote the following function:

```
def strip_date(pid,file_date):
    pid=list(pid)
    pid.remove(file_date)
    return ''.join(pid)

file_date='20190503'
org_df['NewID']=strip_date(org_df['ID'],file_date)
org_df
```

Issues:

1. This is giving me the error message: list.remove(x): x not in list
2. It seems that my current def only removes one file_date in the string; if there are multiple, I have to restrip. e.g. if the id is 'abc_20190503_xyz_20190503', it only strips out the first one. Is there a better solution?

The desired output:

```
New ID             ID                    var1   var2 
abc__xyz         abc_20190503_xyz         100    10
fds__fnk         fds_20190503_fnk         234    32
ree__fds         ree_20190503_fds         555    23
```

Also, I'd like to use New ID as the index.

Comment: `df.ID.str.replace('20190503', '')`

Comment: is the date always the same? or are there multiple?

Comment: date always the same, but will be needed to be pass in as file_date.

Comment: Do you really want that double (or perhaps triple with multiple dates) underscore in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex` for this to extract all numbers from your ID column.

```
df['New_ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('([0-9]+)', '')
```

---

```
print(df)
                 ID  var1  var2    New_ID
0  abc_20190503_xyz   100    10  abc__xyz
1  fds_20190503_fnk   234    32  fds__fnk
2  ree_20190503_fds   555    23  ree__fds
```

Comment: I'd probably change the + in the regex to {8} just in case there are any numbers on the left and right of the date.

Answer (score 1):

`split` then join anything that isn't a number. This will leave a single `'_'` between remaining parts, and will not leave leading or trailing `'_'`.

```
df['New_ID'] = ['_'.join([y for y in x if not y.isdigit()]) for x in df.ID.str.split('_')]

                          ID  var1  var2     New_ID
0           abc_20190503_xyz   100    10    abc_xyz
1           fds_20190503_fnk   234    32    fds_fnk
2           ree_20190503_fds   555    23    ree_fds
3  abc_20190503_xyz_20190503    17    22    abc_xyz
4         abc_20190503_xy10z   100    10  abc_xy10z
```

---

Only segments that can be entirely converted to a number get removed, not all digits in general. If this needs to be just for a single specified date, then can change the check to `if y != '20190503'`